# How to continue past the Nether?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I've completed the Nether and reached the end (the sign) while digging. There is, apparently, no more things to do except buying the plane, which is very expensive.

The next step is, then, amass a lot of "money" to buy the plane? Or I'm supposed to do anything else? I have the lava bucket, which maybe can be used to make the X potion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to buy the plane to advance

Comment: Giving a bit more detail would really help make this a better answer.

Comment: I don't know to say anything else, because I think that's the only thing needed in this stage